# Is there a faster way to merge edges together?

Tags: edges

I have been dragging individual vertices from the outer edges in to the inner edge and merging them. There must be a faster way to sort of collapse the outer edges in to the inner edges. I will be working on more complex shapes and doing it like this is gonna take a lot of time. Hoping there is a faster way. Below on the bottom right of the image, you can see what I am trying to do. Taper it from the bottom till sharp on the inner edge. I need to do this all the way round.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you choose another way around? Keep only one edge, extrude up:

[image]

Select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals* to give it thickness:

[image]

Select the top edge ring, press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Collapse Edges and Faces*:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I need but I need the edge to collapse towards the inner edge and not collapse to the middle. Is there an extra step that can be done to easily align the top vertices to the inner edge vertices of the bottom after this?

Comment: I have figured it out myself and discovered edge slide! Thank you for your help.

Comment: oh yes edge slide is even simpler

Comment: You'll then need to merge vertices by distance after the edge slide if the two edges are on top of each other.

Comment: or just enable the Snap and Auto Merge options